# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in ALLOWED_HOSTS on Django 1.6

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a new django  project on 1.6 version but when I go to sync the database the settings.py returns this error:

```
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/yabir/Documentos/python/project_vine/vine/vine/settings.py", line 29
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

my settings.py before the error

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*******************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

Comment: Can you copy your settings file, specificly the lines before that statement? Most likely you're opening something and forgetting to close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an erronous parenthesis on the previous line. It should be:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), )
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah you forgot to close `TEMPLATE_DIRS`. Change it to:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), )

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```